# D3: Assign ID to Voronoi polygons

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The question is in the title. So far I can construct the Voronoi tesselation polygons by feeding an array of coordinates [x,y] to the following function:

```
var polygon = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "polygons")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(voronoi.polygons(sites))
  .enter().append("path");
```

As mentioned, I would now like to assign an ID to each polygon, but am struggling to do so. What I am trying to do is feed an array that is acceptable for the construction of the Voronoi cells and that also contains the 'ID' (item.name). Here is the code that I am using, and please let me know what I am doing wrong:

```
for (var key in sites) {
  if (sites.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var item = sites[key];
    centroid = projection([item.lon, item.lat]);
    arrayz.push({
    name: item.name,
    coords: [centroid[0], centroid[1]]});
  }
}

var sites = arrayz;

var voronoi = d3.voronoi()
  .extent([
    [-1, -1],
    [width + 1, height + 1]
  ]);

var polygon = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "polygons")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(voronoi.polygons(sites))
  .enter().append("path");

var link = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(voronoi.links(sites))
  .enter().append("line");

var site = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "sites")
  .selectAll("circle.sites")
  .data(sites)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 2.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not giving your voronoi function a way to access the centroid points you're feeding it. This is how I suggest you modify this:

```
var voronoi = d3.voronoi()
  .x( function(d) { return +d.coords[0]; })
  .y( function(d) { return +d.coords[1]; })
  .extent([
    [-1, -1],
    [width + 1, height + 1]
  ]);
```

I am note sure what version of d3 you're using, but with v4 the voronoi.polygons function will output a few points to create the voronoi polygons. It ~also~ outputs the original data you fed it.

In addition to the desired ID, I added an attribute for 'd' which is required to define a svg path.

```
var polygon = g.append("g")
     .attr("class", "polygons")
   .selectAll("path")
   .data(voronoi.polygons(sites))
   .enter().append("path")
     .attr("d", function(d) { return d ? "M" + d.join("L") + "Z" : null; })
     .attr("id", function(d) { return d ? d.data['name'] : null; });
```

I used your code and added everything needed for a working example - check it out: http://bl.ocks.org/zivvers/238713437237c13f21f85b7fd979824d